# BinarySearch Implementation does not work in certain cases

Tags: java, search

I'm a java beginner and I'm trying to code an implementation of the binary search algorithm.

This is my code:

```
    protected int doSearch(List<Integer> list, int key) throws SearchException{

        int min = 0;
        int max = list.size()-1;

        while(max > min){
            int mid = min + ((max-min)/2);
            if(list.get(mid)==key){
                return mid;
            }
            else if(list.get(mid) < key){
                min = mid +1 ;
            }
            else{
                max = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        throw new SearchException("");
    }
```

I tried to copy it from this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm and tried to get it working for lists.

The input list is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]`

If I search for the key `2` the output is `1` which is fine, but if I try for example `1` the SearchException is fired.

I can't explain why. I tried to debug the code by reproducing it on paper, but it worked on the paper.

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm; I'd try on paper again. You could also print out the various values and see if it matches what you're writing down. Working it out on paper is a great idea, though.

Comment: "While the first binary search was published in 1946, the first binary search that works correctly for all values of n did not appear until 1962." Jon Bentley, Programming Pearls

Comment: after 2 iterations you have max == min, the loop exits, the exception is thrown

Comment: @auselen I wonder if one could write a binary search in COBOL ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently inconsistent about whether `max` is an *inclusive* lower bound, as suggested here:

```
int max = list.size()-1;
...
max = mid - 1;
```

or an *exclusive* lower bound, as suggested here:

```
while (max > min)
```

You can make it work either way, so long as you're consistent. Personally I'd suggest using an exclusive upper bound, as that's consistent with things like `list.size()` and computer science in general. So if `mid` is too large, you need to change `max` to *equal* `mid`. Your code will look like this:

```
int max = list.size(); // Note change here

while(max > min) {
    int mid = min + ((max - min) / 2);
    if (list.get(mid) == key) {
        return mid;
    } else if (list.get(mid) < key) {
        min = mid +1 ;
    } else {
        max = mid; // Note change here
    }
}
```

(I've fiddled with the formatting to make it easier to read IMO as well. See whether you prefer it or not.)

Comment: Oh crap, that was the messy part. And I f***ed it up. Thank you so much, it works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest fix is to change:

```
while (max > min) {
```

to:

```
while (max >= min) {
```

You throw the exception in the above because you don't handle that case.